# З'явився бот, що експортує запитання/відповіді з UkrSE до Facebook

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Це зроблено для того, щоб якось популяризувати сайт серед тих, хто не хоче вилазити з Facebook'у. За'follow'ивши відповідну фейсбук-сторінку (кнопка [image: «Стежити»] на ній (або [image: «Follow»] у англійській версії)), користувач зможе отримувати сповіщення про нові запитання/відповіді на сайті у свою стрічку новин у Фейсбуці.

Наразі адреса фейсбучної сторінки така: https://www.facebook.com/ukrse (або ж https://www.facebook.com/811367038989344). Сторінка не призначена для того, щоби прямо на ній запитувати/відповідати (додавання дописів на ній звичайними користувачами взагалі вимкнено), а лише для того, щоб «перенаправляти» відвідувачів (що чимось зацікавилися) сюди.

Кожне запитання на сайті автоматично перетворюється на допис на відповідній сторінці у Facebook, а кожна відповідь — у коментар до нього. При оновленні (редагуванні) запитання/відповіді допис/коментар автоматично оновлюється. Можливо, це пізніше призводитиме до завеликої кількості сповіщень у фейсбук-стрічці — над цим треба подумати: можливо, боту слід перестати реагувати на кожне редагування або зробити кілька окремих сторінок із різною частотою оновлень (одна — про будь-які зміни, інша — про нові відповіді і запитання, третя — лише про нові запитання).

Чого я від вас хочу:

1. Популяризуйте фейсбук-сторінку, якщо маєте бажання (like'айте, поширюйте тощо).
2. Чи маєте якісь побажання щодо змін у боті/сторінці?

**Update: 12–13 грудня 2018 сторінку видалила адміністрація Facebook (імовірно). У принципі, неважко створити нову строрінку й перенаправити бота на неї (це 5 хв. + десь 1 доба роботи бота на перезаповнення сторінки). Але стара сторінка виглядала доволі неоковирно (маю на увазі формат, у якому бот викладав матеріали з цього сайту на Facebook-сторінку), тому я схиляюся до того, щоб поки не перезапускати сторінку, а спочатку доробити бота для кращого формату публікації.**

**Update 2: Адміністрація Facebook (імовірно) відновила сторінку. Тож поки що сторінка знов працює в старому режимі. Сподіваюся, скоро дійдуть руки оновити формат.**

Comment: Яка "типова" затримка між публікацією питання і моментом, коли таке запитання з'являється на https://www.facebook.com/ukrse/?

Comment: @myroslav, наразі сервіс працює так: раз на годину він перевіряє, чи з'явилися протягом цієї години нові запитання/відповіді і, якщо з'явилися, публікує їх поступово з паузами по 5 хвилин (бо Facebook не любить, коли боти публікують декілька дописів майже одночасно). (Можна переналаштувати з іншими значеннями.) (Але іноді стається накладка, наприклад, на цих вихідних, написав про це у ПП.)

Answer (score 4):

Чудово! Було б добре:

1. угіпертекстити стповідомлення. Тобто, з імені користувача посилання прям на його профіль на SE. І т.п.
2. Якщо в питанні використані елементи форматування - жирний шрифт, тодо, то щоб це було видно і в дописі на фейсбук сторінці.

Суть змін, щоб сам допис був якомога зручнішій і цікавіший для читання.

Comment: 1 — наскільки я знаю, у Facebook це неможливо. Можна вставляти пряме посилання після імені (наприклад, `Yola <https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/u/9>` або скорочено через якийсь сервіс скорочення посилань — `Jeff Atwood <http://bit.ly/2w1ofCP>`) — але це збільшить візуальний шум.

Comment: 2 — знов таки, фейсбук не дозволяє форматування. Можливо імітувати форматування використанням [незвичайних символів Unicode](http://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi?text=This+is+pretty+fun+too.+Do+something+for+your+group+tag), але це має недоліки: (а) не для всіх кириличних символів є жирні/курсивні/тощо аналоги; (б) це **не ті** символи, пошук (як Google так і пошук на сторінці в браузері) не працюватиме; (в) дехто бачитиме крадратики.

Comment: Хм… Зараз побачив, що Facebook дозволяє додавати не лише posts, але й [notes](//www.facebook.com/help/488014787881885/) на сторінку. Notes дозволяють форматування. Треба подивитися в цьому напрямку.

Comment: Що я хотів зробити до того, як дізнався про notes — я хотів, щоб воно принаймні не повністю прибирало малюнки (а вставляло скорочені посилання замість малюнків) і вставляло хоча б те оформлення, яке можливо вставляти (`1. `/`2. `/`3. ` чи `• ` для списків, `«»` для цитат). Але перейти з posts на notes — може, навіть, краще. (Також були ідеї вставляти малюнок з уже відформатованим текстом замість простого тексту або змусити Facebook робити красивіші preview для посилань (з малюнком з уже відформатованим текстом замість логотипу) — але це технічно складніше і теж має недоліки.)

Comment: Хоча з notes є дві інші проблеми: (а) вони не підтримуються в API; (б) вони за замовчуванням показуються без форматування (і у вкладеному прямокутнику); щоби показалося форматування, користувач має клацнути (якщо вже клацати — то, може, краще хай вже переходить сюди, ніж відкриває повну версію note?).

Comment: І при цьому [emoji](//www.piliapp.com/facebook-symbols/) у post'ах Facebook підтримує. Тобто замінити окремі Unicode-символи на кольорові картинки — то так, а відформатувати текст чи просто вставити конкретну картинку — то ні. От гадство.